# Tools for Mathematical presentation

Tags: interactive-teaching, online-instruction, presentation

I would like to teach math online I'm wondering what is the tools for mathematical presentation.

- For example, I tired Powerpoint with MathType but with no luck
- Beamer for mathematical presentation but I found it very exhaustive
- https://www.mathcha.io/   Online Mathematics Editor
  a fast way to write and share mathematics

[image]

Comment: No, because I'm interested in tools that make mathematical presentation such as beamer and other devices that specialized only for mathematics

Comment: Maybe I'm too suspicious, but this looks more like an ad than a question.

Comment: This is the only example I know; you can choose whatever you want as an example and put it there.  I don't mind